# MVC .net annotation-based valiadation : Remove dashes and parenthesis from phone numbers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to both validate, that the provided data is in the form of a phone number AND trim it down to just the numbers in the validator?

> **Input:** (902) 837-2832 
>   **Output:** VALID: YES, 9028372832

Or do I have to convert the input to the number-only format after the fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to your model with only a getter that returns the stripped down version of the property that is bound to the input. Put your validation attribute on that property.

```
public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}

[Required(ErrorMessage="Phone number is required.")]
[RegularExpression(@"\d{10}", ErrorMessage="Phone number is invalid.")]
public string PhoneNumberValue
{
    get 
    {
        var temp = PhoneNumber
        temp = Regex.Replace(temp, @"[^0-9]", "");
        temp = temp.Length == 11 && temp.StartsWith("1")
            ? temp.Substring(1) : temp;
    }

    set
    {
        // I can't remember off the top of my head if MVC model
        // binding requires a setter or not. If so, just leave this
        // empty. Otherwise you can remove it entirely.
    }
}
```

Then, in your view, just render the alternate validation message.

```
@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.PhoneNumber)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.PhoneNumber)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.PhoneNumberValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to validate with Regular expression:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage="Phone Number is required")]
 [RegularExpression("^(?([0-9]{3}))?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage="Not a valid number")]
 public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

We may use Trim method of string to clean the phone number and get only digits.

```
char[] charsToTrim = { '(', ' ', ')', '-'};
string phoneNumber = "(123)-345-6789";
string result = banner.Trim(charsToTrim);
```

Finally here is a post that explains [Enabling Validation using DataAnnotations in more detail](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this.  My goal was to isolate the whole solution to one place.  This doesn't completely get me there, but it would solve the problem I think!

Comment: No problem. As was mentioned and referenced on my answer, you may want to create a specific Attribute for your case. The logic of regularexpression and trimming logic should work.